# How do you construct a REST API URI with multiple primary keys?

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, rest

The documentation for [upserting data extension rows](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/v1/hub/data-events/putDataExtensionRowByKey.html) by key uses this as an example URI: https://www.exacttargetapis.com/hub/v1/dataevents/key:SomeKey/rows/Email:someone@exacttarget.com.

Let's say that there are two primary keys for my data extension: Email and ProgramID. How would I construct a URI that contains both of these keys?

**Edit**
I've tried URIs ending with the following:

- .../rows/Email:someone@exacttarget.com,ProgramID:abcd1234
- .../rows/[Email:someone@exacttarget.com,ProgramID:abcd1234]
- .../rows/Email:someone@exacttarget.com/ProgramID:abcd1234

Answer (score 0):

The parameter "primaryKeys" has the type of "array" so you would use the comma character to separate the 2 entries.